# How to display date names (day, month) in Turkish - Php5, Apache2, Intl

Tags: php, apache, intl

I have already installed Intl to my server.

I'v changed my `default_timezone` to Europe/Istanbul and `intl.default_locale` to tr_TR.

I'm still getting the date names in English.

What am i missing?

Should i change some other settings?

Comment: What happens if you add `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR');` at the top of your script?

Comment: @trizz Nothing changes... I don't want to use strftime function. Using new Datetime and format to show my date.

Comment: `setlocale` changes the locale for the entire script and all time/date functions, not only `strftime`. You could check if the locale `tr_TR` is installed at your server with `locale -a` in your SSH shell. If it isn't installed, it will fallback to English.

Comment: Yes it is. I can see tr_TR and tr_TR.utf8 on the list...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/intldateformatter). This is available in PHP's `intl` module, and judging by the title of this question, this extension is available.

A sample/rough implementation:

```
$locale = 'tr_TR'; // a canonicalized locale
$format = 'MMM e'; // ISO format codes, not the typical date ones
$dt = new DateTime(); // a DateTime object
$df = new IntlDateFormatter(
    $locale, // string locale
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int date type
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int time type
    'UTC', // string timezone
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, // int cal type
    $format // string pattern
);
var_dump($dt->format('c')); // string '2014-06-25T08:22:48-07:00' (length=25)
var_dump($df->format($dt)); // string 'Haz 3' (length=5)
```

First and foremost, using any of the Intl* classes is beneficial because you don't need to constantly reset PHP's runtime locale (this can get messy IMO) with `setlocale` or `Locale::setDefault`. This allows you to easily output/format with different locales in a very structured way. It also pushes for use of PHP5's new OOPness -- no more of that `date` nonsense, you should be using `DateTime` now.

The IntlDateFormatter constructor has a fairly long signature, as follows:

1. `$locale` - A canonicalized locale, you can be sure you're getting the right one by filtering your selected Locale through [`Locale::canonicalize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.canonicalize.php).
2. `$dateType` - I set this to 'none' (int `-1`) and use the format parameter (`$pattern`) for maximum flexibility. Accepts 'short', 'medium', 'long', and 'full' as well. You can read more about them in the [ICU project docs](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1DateFormat.html).
3. `$timeType` - Same as `$dateType` but instead dealing with time.
4. `$timezone` - This is *not* an instance of `DateTimeZone`, but instead a string timezone. PHP's `Date` classes are not compatible with intl's classes (the exception is with certain built-in adapters such as the `IntlDateFormatter::format` method).
5. `$calendar` - Typically Gregorian (`null`), but can accept an instance of `IntlCalendar` as well.
6. `$pattern` - Parsing/Rendering format to use, think of this as the equivalent to `date`'s first parameter. However, *they are not the same*: ICU (the underling lib that this class uses) employs an ISO format that is well documented in the [Zend Framework docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.selfdefinedformats). For example, instead of using `'Y'` for a 4 digit year, you would use `'yyyy'`. The ISO format is much more robust than PHP's.

Once you have an instance of `IntlDateFormatter`, as well as a `DateTime` object, you can glue the two together to render out a string containing the date/time you want in the given locale with the given format (as previously defined) using `IntlDateFormatter::format`. The `format` method accepts a single argument: an instance of `DateTime` -- piece of cake!

```
$instanceOfIntlDateFormatter->format($instanceOfDateTime);
```

As a bonus the `format` method can take a wide variety of objects (of type `mixed`), quote:

> Value to format. This may be a `DateTime` object, an `IntlCalendar`
>   object, a numeric type representing a (possibly fractional) number of
>   seconds since epoch or an array in the format output by `localtime()`.

A note about the timezone parameter: `DateTime` changed at version PHP 5.5.0. I have used the following as a workaround (can't remember the details, work it out yourself)...

```
$timezoneForIntl = $instanceOfDateTime->getTimezone();
if ( version_compare(PHP_VERSION,'5.5.0','<') ) {
    $timezoneForIntl = $timezoneForIntl->getName();
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Must be a chapter for a php book :) Well done, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
      <?php
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');
        echo strftime("%e %B %Y %A", time());
      ?>
```

Prints out: 30 Ekim 2015 Cuma

Code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getTurkishDate(){
    $locale = 'tr_TR'; // a canonicalized locale
    $format = 'dd-MMMM-YYYY'; // ISO format codes, not the typical date ones
    $dt = new DateTime(); // a DateTime object
    $df = new IntlDateFormatter(
        $locale, // string locale
        IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int date type
        IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int time type
        'UTC', // string timezone
        IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, // int cal type
        $format // string pattern
    );
    return $df->format($dt); //string 07-Ağustos-2018
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and kudos for diving straight in to answer a question. In order to be of maximum help to people who come across your answer later, it's useful to add some explanation rather than just code. See [answer].